# Apex code to update new Opportunity with values from related object

Tags: apex

What would be the proper method to update a list of new Opportunities with the values from a related record.

```
for (Opportunity opps:Trigger.new){
[SELECT Id, CorpOwner__r, Contact__r,(SELECT Id, AccountLocation from Account)]
o.CorpOwner__r =Account.Id; o.AccountLocation = opps.Account.AccountLocation; 
insert opps
```

Do you call the lookup fields by the __r suffix? Could you do a before insert operation and still look up the Opportunity.CorpOwner__r relationship to values in the CorpOwner__r Account record, or does that relationship not exist since the record has not been created? What would be a proper batchified way to go about it?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a possibility that demonstrates a number of concepts:

```
trigger UpdateOpptyWithAccountInfo on Opportunity (before insert) {

    // Keep this SOQL query out of the FOR loop for better efficiency/batching
    Map<Id, Account> relatedAccounts = new Map<Id, Account>(
      [SELECT Id, AccountLocation__c
       FROM Account
       WHERE Id IN
         (SELECT AccountId
         FROM Opportunity
         WHERE Id = :Trigger.new)
     ]
   );

   for (Opportunity o : Trigger.new) {

     /* Find each opportunity's Account in the map we queried for earlier
      * Note: there's probably a more efficient way to use a Map of Opportunity IDs to Account objects...
      * This works fine and could be more readable.
      */
     for (Account a : relatedAccounts.values()) {

       if (a.Id == o.AccountId) {

         // Once you've found the account related to this opportunity, update the values
         o.CorpOwner__c = a.Id;
         o.AccountLocation__c = a.AccountLocation__c; 
       }
     }
   }

   // We're still inside an `insert` trigger, so no need to call `insert` again.
   // The new fields will be inserted along with everything else.

}
```

If you're establishing the relationship between objects, use the `__c` suffix:

```
o.CorpOwner__c = a.Id;  // Associate Account `a` as Opportunity `o`'s CorpOwner
```

If you're looking up a field on a related object, then you would use `__r`:

```
System.debug(o.CorpOwner__r.Name);  // Print Opportunity `o`'s CorpOwner's name
```